# Latex in MacOS powerpoint

Tags: equations, macos, physics, powerpoint

I've been using beamer on Linux for over 8 years, but my new work now wants me to make powerpoint presentations on a MacBook and I feel very lost. I struggle with the equation editor. My administrative settings won't let me install IguanaTex. I've gotten LatexIt to work, but I can't make it work for commands defined by the physics package. Does anyone have any tips to help me with this transition?

How do I get LatexIt to understand commands defined in the physics package?
If Latex is natively available in powerpoint, how do I get it to understand commands from the physics package.

Thank you,

Comment: Make the presentations with `beamer` (on Overleaf if your job doesn't allow installing LaTeX locally) and import the pdf slides into Powerpoint or Keynote - only half joking, this may be the fastest/easiest way to use (physics) equations.

Comment: I've never found an efficient way to import multiple pages from a pdf to Keynote, or to convert a .pdf to Keynote. But my understanding is that that's easier with Powerpoint.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LaTeXit is a great program for creating LaTeX snippets for Powerpoint presentations. And if you're sharing with people who are used to Powerpoint, it's definitely the way to go, as opposed to using `beamer`  Also, `beamer` has a very high markup to content ratio, which makes it quite time consuming to create without a bit of upfront planning, and if you need the presenter mode that Powerpoint offers, there really isn't equivalent functionality for PDFs in my experience.

But it's easy to modify the preamble for any LaTeXit snippet. If you open a new snippet you can choose to edit the preamble:

[image: edit preamble]

When you do so you see a split window like the following:

[image: specific preamble]

As you can see, my preamble contains specific packages that I use for linguistics, including `forest` for trees, and `gb4e` for linguistic examples. So in your case you can add the `physics` package to gain all the macro functionality associated with that package.

If you're going to be using the same preamble for lots of documents, you can save it from the Templates panel of the LaTeXit preferences panel.

In this panel you can see the currently saved preambles that I have. The default preamble provided by LaTeXit, and some custom preambles for different things. So you can create a preamble specifically to meet your needs and make that the default for new or existing documents.

[image: saved preamble]